# DRO, Picture Profile and Auto Mode - Why these settings can’t coexist?

Tags: sony, dynamic-range, manual-mode

I’m new to professional photography and still trying to understand some crucial things,I really hope you guys could help me out.

I have a Sony A6500, I’m trying to move from Auto to Manual settings, testing Picture Profiles and learning about DRO but there are two things I can’t understand.

1) Why can’t I use Picture Profiles on Auto mode?

2) Why can’t I use DRO when using Picture Profiles?

I’ve search a lot about this, find pretty usefull information about why PP don’t affect RAW files, including the following:

*“In Auto mode, the Picture Profile is locked in. It is still there and applied to show you the preview.”*

If there is a Picture Profile in Auto mode why can’t I change it or edit the values?

These questions may be obvious to most of you, but it doesn’t make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

"Auto" mode is designed to prevent an inexperienced user from making bad decisions. In order to do this, the camera makes as many decisions as it can on its own, based on how it is programmed to respond to different shooting conditions.

If you want to control things such as Picture Profiles or DRO without going to full manual control, you need to get out of full "Auto" mode and into one of the "semi-automatic" modes, such as Program, Shutter Priority, or Aperture priority. These modes will give you a bit more control while still calculating the final value for exposure. These modes will also allow you to make bigger mistakes.